# need someone to look at this javascript code i dont know how to solve this

Tags: javascript

I've created a Rock Paper scissors game using JavaScript, I want to show an image of element that won in the end. 
For example: 
If rock wins: show a image/jpg of a rock 
If paper wins: show a image/jpg of a paper

Below is the code:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
//console.log("Computer chooses: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!" + " " + "Lets play again.";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {

        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins" + "<br>" + "You beat the computer, nice job!";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins" + "<br>" + "Your really smart computer beat you.";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {

        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins" + "<br>" + "You beat the computer, nice job!";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins" + "<br>" + "Your really smart computer beat you.";
        }
    }

    else if (choice1 === "scissors") {

        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "rock wins" + "<br>" + "Your really smart computer beat you.";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors win" + "<br>" + "You beat the computer, nice job!";
        }
    }


} //closes compare function
document.write("Computer chose: " + computerChoice + "<br>");
document.write(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

Comment: look at the question - can you read it? so many blank lines, almost no indentation - needs a lot of work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help a lot if you could try to format your source code esp. regarding indentation.

Comment: `show a jpg` - document.write wont do that - try again

Comment: Does the code you provided have anything to do with displaying an image?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can just use the following selector / method to change the src image of an HTML img tag:

> document.getElementById("your-img").src = 'rock.jpg';

Of course you have to set the image path and the id accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
computerChoice = Math.random()
```

Use math.floor()

```
computerChoice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)
```

Now use this to tell what the computer meant:

```
if(computerChoice == '1') { computerChoice = 'stone' };
if(computerChoice == '2') { computerChoice = 'paper' };
if(computerChoice == '3') { computerChoice = 'scissors' };
```